# How can I wire a panel heater?

Tags: electrical, ring-main

Bought my Mum a Dimplex Panel Heater for Christmas.

My plan was to plug it into the single socket beside where I am mounting it however it did not come with a plug and look like it should be wired into a fused unit.

Can I just stick a 13A plug on it and use existing socket? Its only 0.5KWH.

Comment: Could you link to the product, or include a model number?  Is it designed to be installed as a permanent fixture (hard wired)?

Comment: Product URL: http://www.alertelectrical.com/prod/76/dimplex-electric-panel-convector-heater-05kw-output

Comment: Found the [Installation Instructions](http://www.dimplex.de/downloads/uploads/dimplex_plx500-3000_fd8512_fr-2009-07-23.pdf), but could only find it in French and German (neither of which I can read).

Comment: The picture on the product page appears to show a heater that is wired directly as opposed to plugged into an outlet.

Comment: [Google translated English installation instructions](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dimplex.de%2Fdownloads%2Fuploads%2Fdimplex_plx500-3000_fd8512_fr-2009-07-23.pdf)

Comment: One consideration: it's not CE/UL/CSA/whatever-approved to have a plug, and so if a fire was ever [suspected to be] caused by this, your insurance company may not have to pay the claim.

Comment: [Natively English instructions](http://www.dimplex.com/cms/publications/DEC_Series_-_Delux_Electronic_Panel_Convection_Heater_-_Owners_Manual,_Model_%23DEC_-_7204310100R04_EN.pdf). At .5KW, I don't see why you can't stick a regular 13 amp plug (fuse it to 3 amps) on there, but I'm completely unfamiliar with the electric codes over there... I'm shocked at .5KW, though. My electric plug-in 120 volt one here is 1.4KW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are designed to permanently wired through a fused switch. As gregmac points out in [his comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11174/how-can-i-wire-a-panel-heater#comment15069_11174) there may be insurance issues if you use a normal plug and socket, particularly in area of fire risks.

However, you can replace the current socket with a fused switch panel. Make sure you get one with a hole in the surface for the wire to go through.

Something [like this](http://www.oceanlighting.co.uk/switches-sockets-c140/satin-chrome-sockets-switches-c144/click-deco-scolmore-international-click-deco-vpsc052-13-amp-fused-switched-connection-unit-with-flex-outlet-and-neon-satin-chrome-finish-with-black-or-white-inserts-p7701?utm_source=froogle&utm_medium=ppc&utm_term=click-deco-scolmore-international-click-deco-vpsc052-13-amp-fused-swit-finish-colour-white-inserts&utm_campaign=froogle#8863)